# ContextMenu Excel 365 action is lost after a while c#

Tags: c#, excel

I've created a contextMenu (CommandBarButton) in an excel ribbon addin written in C# some time ago. I notice that for some reason after a while working in excel the functionality behind the button is lost. Immediately after initialization of the addin where the buttons are added to the context menu it works like a charm but then after being busy in the Excel sheet the function behind the event is not called anymore when I click on it.

I tried a lot of different things like removing and adding the events after every action in my addin but the problem persists.

EDIT: I found out that a button in my ribbon which copies the worksheet is (at least one of the cases) responsible for making the event handler being inoperative. I use the `Excel.Worksheet.Copy()` to copy my worksheet, also activate a filter renders the event handler inoperative.

Maybe for some reason the event listener is removed by some process?

```
        Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton ContextMenuCompanyButton;
        ContextMenuCompanyButton = (Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton)Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars["Cell"].Controls.Add(Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoControlType.msoControlButton, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, 1, false);
        ContextMenuCompanyButton.Style = Microsoft.Office.Core.MsoButtonStyle.msoButtonCaption;
        ContextMenuCompanyButton.Caption = "Companies";
        ContextMenuCompanyButton.Tag = "Companies";
        ContextMenuCompanyButton.Visible = true;
        ContextMenuCompanyButton.Click += new Microsoft.Office.Core._CommandBarButtonEvents_ClickEventHandler(CommandBarCompanyButton_Click);
```

Does somebody know the problem, I do not know where to look for it. Maybe there is some internal process clearing these events?

Comment: I found out that a button in my ribbon which copies the worksheet is (at least one of the cases) responsible of making the event handler being inoperative. I use the Excel.Worksheet.Copy() to copy my worksheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed it!

The first row of the code I posted in my question:

```
Microsoft.Office.Core.CommandBarButton ContextMenuCompanyButton;
```

I moved as a class variable to the header of the class.